# How to lock users account until approvation

Tags: php, plugin-development, users, user-roles

I have created a custom role that I've named `customer`

```php
public function setup_user_roles()
{
  add_role('customer', 'Customer', $customer_capabilities);
  add_role('moderator', 'Moderator', $moderator_capabilities);
}
```

I've used the plugin registration hook to add them and the capabilities are only `read` for the `customer` and only `edit_users` for moderator role. I need to give to users te ability to modify only their own profile informations and for modeartors the ability to approve accounts. Not sure if I need to add other capabilities to achive this, at the moment the two roles are added to wp roles and seems working as expected. What I need is to have the accounts of the customers not able to login until thay are approved from a moderator. I've added a custom meta field that will have the status `pending`, `approved` or `rejected` but how I can rely on it when users try to login? Is there a better way for this without an external plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Wordpress has ability to prevent user access without acceptation. You should uncheck "Anyone can register" on the /wp-admin/options-general.php